# Mapping a list of objects within another object in SOQL using the Force.com Toolkit for .NET

Tags: c#, salesforce, soql

I'm trying to query SalesForce using the [Force.com Toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET). After playing around with the example code I noticed you can map the result of a query to an object as so:

```
   private class Account
    {
        public const String SObjectTypeName = "Account";
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Where you can assign the query result as such:

```
var results = await client.QueryAsync<Account>(qry);
```

What I'm wondering about is how I map a Contacs object within the account object if I have something like this:

```
   private class Account
    {
        public const String SObjectTypeName = "Account";
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public List<Contact> contacs{get;set;}
    }
   private class Account
    {
        public const String SObjectTypeName = "Contacs";
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

    }
```

And my query looks like this:

```
Select id,Name, (Select, id, name From Contacs) from Account
```

What I'm expecting is a list of contacts related to the Account object.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick....

```
private class Account
{
    public const String SObjectTypeName = "Account";
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public ContactsResult Contacts { get; set; }
}
private class ContactsResult
{
    public Contacts[] Records { get; set; }
}
private class Contacts
{        
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally you can always cast the results to an object which will return the json result and you can use a tool such as http://json2csharp.com/ to create the model for you.